# How not to vibrate with AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1336)

Tags: ios, swift

I have `import AudioToolbox` and then `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1336)` later in the code to play a system sound. It works but also vibrates which is not needed. Why does it vibrate? and how can I make it not to? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1336` is `Update.caf`, which is part of the SMSReceived_Selection category. It will cause a vibration if the iOS device is set to vibrate when SMS messages are received.

If you don't want the vibration, just extract this sound and use it on your own instead of using `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound()`.

Comment: nice, how do i extract it?